# How to write python script to read data from a generic data file and write to a .x?

Tags: python

I'm a student working with a rather old program, and I must use an uncommon file format for which I can't find any file conversion. It seems I have to write a script to convert the data I need myself. I don't know how to manipulate text files well enough to solve this issue.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

I have data in the form of:

```
Garbage Text1
Garbage Text2
I=2, J=3, K=1 Garbage Text
Garbage Text4
x1 y1 z1
x2 y2 z2
x3 y3 z3
x4 y4 z4
x5 y5 z5
x6 y6 z6
Garbage Text1
Garbage Text2
I=3, J=3, K=1 Garbage Text
Garbage Text4
x7 y7 z7
x8 y8 z8
x9 y9 z9
x10 y10 z10
x11 y11 z11
x12 y12 z12
x13 y13 z13
x14 y14 z14
x15 y15 z15
```

which has to be converted into a Plot3D .x file:

```
2                !number of blocks
2 3 1            !I,J,K of each block
3 3 1            !I,J,K of each block
x1 x2 x3 x4      !List of each I coordinate, followed by J then K,
x5 x6            !divided into columns of four. The total number of
y1 y2 y3 y4      !points does not need to be divisible by four.
y5 y6
z1 z2 z3 z4
z5 z6
x7 x8 x9 x10     !Next block.
x11 x12 x13 x14
x15 x16
y7 y8 y9 y10
y11 y12 y13 y14
y15 y16
z7 z8 z9 z10
z11 z12 z13 z14
z15 z16
```

```
This_is_line_5
ZONE T="ZONE 001"
 STRANDID=0, SOLUTIONTIME=0
 I=41, J=141, K=1, ZONETYPE=Ordered
 DATAPACKING=POINT
 DT=(SINGLE SINGLE SINGLE )
 9.977060556E-01 -2.960788086E-02 0.000000000E+00
 9.976553321E-01 -2.978901565E-02 0.000000000E+00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex and some for loops to scrape the data you wanted from the file.
Here is the code I wrote for your example data, it works with your provided example (I replaced x,y and z coordinates with numbers):

```
import re
filename = 'data.txt'

class Block:
    def __init__(self, i:int, j:int, k:int):
        self.i = i
        self.j = j
        self.k = k
        self.xs = []
        self.ys = []
        self.zs = []

with open(filename, 'r') as file:
    raw_data = file.readlines()

blocks = []
block = Block(0, 0, 0)
while raw_data:
    line = raw_data[0]
    if re.match("I=\d*, J=\d*, K=\d*", line):
        blocks.append(block)
        i, j, k = re.findall("I=(\d*), J=(\d*), K=(\d*)", line)[0]
        block = Block(int(i), int(j), int(k))
    elif re.match("\d* \d* \d*", line):
        x, y, z = re.findall("(\d*) (\d*) (\d*)", line)[0]
        block.xs.append(x)
        block.ys.append(y)
        block.zs.append(z)
    raw_data.pop(0)
blocks.pop(0)
blocks.append(block)

# Print scraped data's count
print(len(blocks))

# Print I, J, K for each block
for block in blocks:
    print(block.i, block.j, block.k)

# Print x, y, z coordinates for each block
for block in blocks:
    # Print x coordinates
    i = 0
    temp = ''
    for x in block.xs:
        temp += x + ' '
        i += 1
        if i%4 == 0 and i/4 >= 1:
            print(temp)
            temp = ''
    if temp:
        print(temp)
        
    # Print y coordinates
    i = 0
    temp = ''
    for y in block.ys:
        temp += y + ' '
        i += 1
        if i%4 == 0 and i/4 >= 1:
            print(temp)
            temp = ''
    if temp:
        print(temp)
    
    # Print z coordinates
    i = 0
    temp = ''
    for z in block.zs:
        temp += z + ' '
        i += 1
        if i%4 == 0 and i/4 >= 1:
            print(temp)
            temp = ''
    if temp:
        print(temp)
```

This is just my spaghetti, you can try refactoring it. Feel free to ask any question about it.

Comment: Wow this is way more robust than I was expecting. Incredible. Reading through it, it appears to do everything I need. When running it, I do see a syntax error on line 5, pointing to the first colon. I'm not sure what to do about this.

Comment: I updated to python 3.6.5 to solve the syntax issue, but I'm now seeing "blocks.pop(0) IndexError: pop from empty list". My guess is that the match or findall functions are returning empty. I've added some of one of the files to be converted to the posted question. Thank you!

Comment: @BrendanMcBreen You need some changes in regex patterns, this pattern works with the sample you provided at first.

Comment: try adding a space at start of the patterns

Comment: and you need to change second condition patterns to recognize your numbers (since they are not decimal integers, my pattern works for positive integers)